# Is there a good way to enable the "open link in a new window" browser menu option on a dom node, without making the link followed on-click?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I want to have a complex dom node have the "open link in new window" context menu option, like you have with any standard <a> tag link. But I don't want that dom node to open up that link when clicked. What are my options?

The option I'm doing right now is causing me trouble. I'm currently setting up a click handler on the <a> node that calls `event.preventDefault()`. The problem with this is that it prevents the default on EVERYTHING inside that <a> tag. If I have a checkbox, for example, the checkbox becomes unselectable by mouse click. I can futz around with stuff so that it works out (by using `stopPropagation()` in the right places), but this is incredibly confusing and will likely waste me and my team hours in the future. Is there a less hacky way of doing this?

Example of the type of html I have:

```
<a href="www.whatever.ninja">
  <input type='checkbox'/>
  <div contenteditable="true">Your cursor could be |here!</div>
  <div>More content...</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a class to the <a> tag, and then make your preventDefault call only apply to elements with that class. That way, you can style it so that it doesn't look like a link, as well. Are you using something like jQuery? You could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.non-clickable').click(function() {
        $(this).preventDefault();
    });
});
```

and then in your html:

```
<a href="mylink" class="non-clickable">Some link text</a>
```

Comment: I have a complex dom node *inside* the <a> tag. I'll add an example of what I have.

Comment: So how does the class help me prevent the default of the <a> tag without preventing the default of my checkbox?

Comment: You might want to have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct. The upshot is: 'HTML 5 states that the <a> element "may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links)"'.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'm not having problems with interactive elements in chrome - other than that it looks like i'm simply not given enough degrees of freedom.